# Ember fails when changing ID value

Tags: routes, ember.js

I currently have my route setup so that all boats is at the root `/` and I can go to a specific boat by going to `/boats/:boat_id`

For whatever reason, if I leave the ID set to `:boat_id`, then the root will not show any boats and throws this error in the console:

> Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.

If I change it to just `:id`, then the root works fine but `/boats/{any id}` doesn't work. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
BoatBuilder.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('boats', { path: '/' });
  this.resource('boat', { path: '/boat/:boat_id' }, function() {
    this.route("motor");
    this.route("accessories");
  });

  this.route("summary");
});

BoatBuilder.BoatsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return BoatBuilder.Boat.find();
  }
});

BoatBuilder.Boat = DS.Model.extend({
  iem_name: DS.attr('string'),
  url_text: DS.attr('string'),
  price_retail: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Comment: can you provide feed back, if my suggested solution resolved your issue. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If your model does not use the id property in the url, you should define a serialize method on your route. See http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/.

Also, if you are accessing /boats/:boat_id through a #linkTo, you will also need to add the serialize hook in your router.

Adapted from the ember guides link I pasted above, it should be something like this:

```
 App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('boat', { path: '/boat/:boat_id' };
 });

 App.BoatRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function(params) {
           // the server returns 

      },

    serialize: function(model) {
       // this will make the URL `/boat/:boat_id`
     return { boat_id: model.id };
    }
 });
```

You may need to tweak it to meet you need.

Answer (score 0):

> If I change it to just :id, then the root works fine but /boats/{any id} doesn't work. Any ideas?

Using your actual router map should going to a specific boat not be like this?

```
/boat/:boat_id
```

and all boats like this:

```
/
```

Comment: Tried that, no dice :-(

Comment: @WebDevDude, have edited my answer, what is happening doing what I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you need a resource for `boats` as you don't have nested routes inside. So try:

```
BoatBuilder.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('boats', { path: '/' });
  this.resource('boat', { path: '/boat/:boat_id' }, function() {
    this.route("motor");
    this.route("accessories");
  });

  this.route("summary");
});
```